# Are character comparisons appropriate questions?

Tags: discussion

Are questions of the form:

- Character A Vs. Character B

or

- What the similarities between these two characters

or

- Was one based on the other?

There are a few Star Wars characters I've been thinking about that have some similarities in their character, but I have a feeling this might not be an appropriate. I guess they could end up list like on one hand, but if they are intentionally similar by design I would think it could be on topic.

First time posting in meta by the way, so this might even be an inappropriate question about an inappropriate question.

Comment: This is a good question.  Not awake enough yet to post anything coherent... But I think the question being good quality with evidence of research,  and justification for your assumptions works go a long way.

Comment: I think this would be OK provided it's not opinion-based. Best of all would be "has Lucas/Abrams/the relevant actors/someone involved in the production ever commented on the similarities between characters A and B?" Also OK: "is there any canon evidence that character A was based on character B?" *Not* OK: "do you think character A was based on character B?" or just "was character A based on character B?" without further detail.

Comment: Yes, what @randal'thor said. If you ask for word-of-god evidence (or any other evidence that can be objectively weighed - e.g. very specific measurable speech patterns) it is unquestionably a good question.

Comment: If you're simply looking for *confirmation* that Character A is similar to Character B ([amiright?!!!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=amiright)) but without any special expectation that there will be actual evidence that one is based on the other, then the answer is that the question is liable to be on-topic but will get downvoted to Hades. I guess there also needs to be some actual reason to assume one is like the other.

Comment: @Richard So if there is some initial evidence to suggest similarities I could ask the question for the purpose of finding further similarities?

Comment: @Hatandboots - Yes, but beyond the answer "*yes, I've found a brief quote from the artist saying that they did/didn't base their character on y*", what are you hoping to find out? I'm not saying that trivial questions are bad, but those that provoke *trivial answers* are bad.

Comment: @Richard Hmm well I guess ideally the answer would first confirm A is based on B and then identify further parallels between them.

Comment: Worth a read https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/